# Are the tension on the two strings that constrain a particle that is doing circular motion the same?

Tags: classical-mechanics

may I know whether the tension on the two strings are the same, the picture is attached. 
[image]

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: If there is gravity, the answer would have to be "No", because the A string is taking all the force of gravity in the left-hand picture, but shares it with the B string in the right-hand picture.

Comment: Physicsstackexchange is the next door. EDIT: Just saw calssical mechanics tag, so physicists made their way in here. OMG

Comment: If there is no gravity, you still expect the tensions to be different because there is no vertical acceleration, so the vertical components of the tension must cancel out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the tension in the upper string is $T_1$ and in the lower string $T_2$. Let the radius be $r$, the speed $v$ and the mass $m$.

Resolving vertically we get $T_1\cos\theta=T_2\cos\phi+mg$ (assuming there is gravity - leave out the $mg$ if not). Resolving horizontally we get $T_1\sin\theta+T_2\sin\phi=mv^2/r$.

So in general we do not expect $T_1=T_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That just solved my problem.